# Is there a better way to extract the dataset from a nodelist?

Tags: javascript

I have the following list.

```
<div class="taco" data-id="2"></div>
<div class="taco" data-id="3"></div>
<div class="taco" data-id="4"></div>
<div class="taco" data-id="23"></div>
<div class="taco" data-id="55"></div>
```

and I use the following code to get all of them in a list.

```
let tacos = document.querySelectorAll(".taco");
```

Then I use the following code to get all the datasets

```
let tacosArray = [];
for (let i = 0; i < tacos.length; index++) {
   tacosArray.push(tacos[i].dataset.id);
}
```

I now have an array of datasets, but there has to be a better way.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is `Array.from` with its mapper function.

```js
const tacos = Array.from(
  document.querySelectorAll('.taco'),
  div => div.dataset.id
);
console.log(tacos);
```

```html
<div class="taco" data-id="2"></div>
<div class="taco" data-id="3"></div>
<div class="taco" data-id="4"></div>
<div class="taco" data-id="23"></div>
<div class="taco" data-id="55"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

The spread operator `...` and `.map()`

```js
const ids = [...document.querySelectorAll('.taco')].map(id => id.dataset.id);

console.log(JSON.stringify(ids));
```

```html
<div class="taco" data-id="2"></div>
<div class="taco" data-id="3"></div>
<div class="taco" data-id="4"></div>
<div class="taco" data-id="23"></div>
<div class="taco" data-id="55"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. It seems that the spread operator has many uses, I was honestly unaware of how many things you can do with it. Thank you.